# Determining if Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me get and understand this concept of linear algebra based on this questions:

Determine whether or not $T$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ if u$ \in \mathbb{R^2} $ and v$ \in \mathbb{R^2}$, and $T(x,y)=(x+1,x+y)$

I understand the 3 basic rules:

a) $T$( u+v)=$T$(u)+$T$(v)

b) $T(\alpha $u)=$\alpha T$(u)

c) $T($0)=0

Answer (score 1):

For any linear transformation $T(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$. This follows from either considering property a) with $\vec{v} = -\vec{u}$ or considering property b) with $\alpha = 0$.

Now, does $T(0,0) = (0,0)$ hold for the transformation $T(x,y) = (x+1,x+y)$?

If not, then the transformation is not linear.

In general, if you want to determine wether a transformation is linear, you need to either verify that both a) and b) hold true for all $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \alpha$, or you need to find a counterexample to show that one of a) and b) does not hold true.

Comment: how to do that is my question. It's not clear to me how I would start verifying this using the values provided.

Comment: Did you try plugging in $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ into $T(x,y) = (x+1,x+y)$ to see if $T(0,0) = (0,0)$?

Comment: Are you saying that for the 3 conditions, all we need to do is substitute for values =$(0+1, 0+0) =T(1,0)\neq T(0,0)$

Comment: First of all, $T(1,0) = (2,1)$ not $(0+1,0+0) = (1,0)$, so the equation you just wrote is incorrect. 

Second, to show that a transformation is not linear, you just need to show that one of those conditions is not satisfied. In this case, I'm suggesting that you show that the 3rd condition is not met, since thats pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @jimmyk4542 for the response. However, you can almost guest from question that real problem lies in knowing how to apply these conditions. To avoid a different thread asking the same questions, can you show it is done with, say, condition a). The response is throwing me into confusion especially, how you come up with T(1,0)=(2,1).

Comment: To find the value of $T(0,0)$, start with $T(x,y) = (x+1,x+y)$. Replace $x$ with $0$ and $y$ with $0$, which gives you $T(0,0) = (0+1,0+1)$. Simplify this to obtain $T(0,0) = (1,0)$. This shows that $T(0,0) = (1,0) \neq (0,0)$. So $T$ is not linear. Since condition c) isn't met, we don't need to check a) or b).